# How do PPM FM channels work?

Tags: frequency-modulation

I know the difference between AM and FM. What I don't get clearly is how the transmitter with a single antenna can transmit up to nine different channels with almost no interference between channels. I am trying to build an 72 MHz or 40 MHz radio control. The problem is that I build RC submarines, and the 2.4 GHz does not work at all in the water. It only works on the surface.

I want to  build a transmitter that picks the PWM output of a modern 2.4 GHz RX and re-transmits the signal in 72 MHz or 40 MHz. The lower frequency the better results I get. Old 40 MHz FM radio works like charm in an RC sub.

I found this circuit of a single channel FM transmitter that claims that works fine and with a respectable 1 W output. Could that circuit help me?
http://www.electroschematics.com/2436/1-watt-fm-transmitter/

Comment: Please learn to use capitalisation, punctuation and paragraphs to make your questions readable. e.g. 'mhz' (milli-hertz) instead of 'MHz' mega-hertz, 'fm' -> 'FM', 'rc' -> 'RC'. Fixed.

Comment: That FM transmitter is not crystal controlled and so probably won't have the required frequency stability. Here's a circuit designed for R/C:- http://myweb.tiscali.co.uk/norcimradiocontrol/Radio3.htm. Alternatively you could use a plug-in R/C tx module, or remove the board from an old r/c transmitter (doesn't have to be a fancy radio as you will only be using the RF part).

Answer (score 2):

PPM = Pulse Position Modulation. Multiple servo channels are sent on the same frequency using a form of Time Division Multiplexing. The PPM modulator first sends a start pulse, then sends a pulse for each channel (making a total of 10 pulses for 9 channels). The time between leading or trailing edges represents the servo PWM pulse width (typically 1~2ms). Finally a gap significantly greater than the maximum servo pulse width is required so the receiver can synchronize to the start pulse. This whole sequence is called a frame.

If all 9 channels are at their maximum width then the minimum time required to transmit 1 frame is 9*2ms + >2ms = >20ms (or even longer if the maximum servo pulse width is greater than 2ms). A frame period of 22ms is commonly used, corresponding to a repetition rate of ~45Hz.

[image]

Many R/C transmitters have a 'trainer' port which outputs a PPM pulse stream. Pulse polarity and amplitude vary depending on the brand and model of transmitter. The pulses may be AC or DC coupled, positive or negative going, and anywhere from 1V to 12V in amplitude. You will need to identify what signal levels are present, and if necessary convert them to the levels required by your FM transmitter.

A positive going PPM signal may either increase or decrease the transmission frequency of your FM transmitter, depending on what FM modulator circuit it uses. At the receiving end this may cause the pulses to come out either positive or negative going. Some receivers have switchable or automatic polarity detection, others are fixed and need to have the correct modulation 'shift' in order to decode the signal properly. If the 'shift' is wrong you just need to invert the PPM signal sent to the FM transmitter.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is how does a transmitter circuit tune to different frequencies, and this is done just like a receiver, with a process called hetrodyning. The transmitter has several stages, an baseband stage (original pwm signal) and the baseband 'beats' (mixes) with an if stage to produce an intermediate rf signal, (lower than the transmit rf stage). This is done so that you have a common signal to amplify, reducing the amount of circuitry and cost. The final stage is the RF stage, and a common component (variable capacitor) is used at both the final if stage and the rf stage to beat the signal to the transmit frequency. By adding a digital control to the variable capacitor, you can switch back and forth between 2 frequencies.

Comment: How about a link to an authoritative source verifying your claim?